# How to include a user profile picture in author's page in Wordpress if the user has no post

Tags: php, wordpress

For a Wordpress website, with multiple editors/authors, I am trying to create an author page that automatically include the author name, avatar, bio and created posts.

Everything was working fine for users that have created at least 1 post, but things get tricky for users who did not created any post.

So far, I've managed, for this kind of users, to add both the name and the bio, but not the profile pic..

Can somebody help me?

Here is the code for my author.php

```
        <?php
    
    
    get_header();
    ?>
    
    
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">
            <main id="main" class="site-main">
    
                <?php
                
                do_action('refined_magazine_before_main_content');
    
    
                /**
                 * refined_magazine_breadcrumb hook.
                 *
                 * @since 1.0
                 * @hooked refined_magazine_construct_breadcrumb -  10
                 *
                 */
                do_action('refined_magazine_breadcrumb');
    
                if (have_posts() ) : ?>
    
                    <header class="page-header">
                        <?php
                        the_archive_title('<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>');
                        ?>
                        <div class="author-wrapper" style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap; display:inline !important;>
                        <div class="author-photo" style="display:inline-block; width:10%; ">
        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>
    
        </div>
        <div class="author-bio" style="display:inline-block; width:85%; padding-left:20px; ">
     <?php
                        the_archive_description('<div class="archive-description">', '</div>');
                        ?>
    
        </div>
        
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->
                    
    
                    <div class="ct-post-list clearfix">
                        <?php
                        /* Start the Loop */
                        while (have_posts()) :
                            the_post();
    
                            /*
                             * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                             * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                             * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                             */
                            get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_type());
    
                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <?php
    
                    
                    do_action('refined_magazine_action_navigation');
    
                else :
                
                
                                
                    $author = get_queried_object();
                    
                 ?>
                 <header class="page-header">
                 
                        <h1 class="page-title">
                        <?php
                        echo $author->first_name . ' ' . $author->last_name;
                        ?>
                        
                        </h1>
                        <div class="author-wrapper" style="width:100%; white-space:nowrap; display:inline !important;>
                        <div class="author-photo" style="display:inline-block; width:10%; ">
        <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>
    
        </div>
        <div class="author-bio" style="display:inline-block; width:85%; padding-left:20px; ">
     <?php
                        
                    echo $author->description;
                        ?>
    
        </div>
        
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->
                <?php endif;
    
                /**
                 * refined_magazine_after_main_content hook.
                 *
                 * @since 0.1
                 */
                do_action('refined_magazine_after_main_content');
                ?>
    
            </main><!-- #main -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
    
    <?php
    
    do_action('refined_magazine_sidebar');
    
    get_footer();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's not working... ...if you have the author's ID and they have a gravatar uploaded, then I don't see why the code would be any different regardless of whether or not they have existing posts.

Comment: @Tony Djukic. On the website, there is a page filled with members of the staff. Each team member short description, in the page °Team° is linked to a personal page with  bio, avatar and written posts. This is, basically, an author page, the same that you get when clicking on the author's name on any posted article. Now. If there are, published posts, I correctly display everything needed, otherwise, I would gate an empty page. I've managed to get the user name and bio also for this users, but instead of the image uploaded in the profile, I see an empty placeholder.

Comment: Are you sure the author in question has a picture uploaded?  Once you have their `user->ID` I don't see any reason why the code would behave any different whether they have posts or not.

Comment: Inded I am sure, I am not using Gravatar, since the admin need to manage all of users accounts and thus being able to upload and change pics himself. I think the problem is precisely with the ID. Normally WP gets the ID of the author of a post. Since there is no post, it has no ID to get. For the same reason, I had to use a different way to include name and bio for users without any posted article

Comment: Ok, then I'm not understanding where you're displaying these authors.  If you have a pre-set list of authors then you have the IDs.  If you're sending users from a list of authors to an individual author's page, then you already have the ID/info for that author.  I see no indication above that you're relying on the post to get the author ID and it wouldn't make sense to do so since this is the `author.php` not a post.

Comment: There is a staff page with the name of staff members that needed to be linked, each one to it's own authoràs page. The actual info displayed in the author's page, are written in the "users" section in WP, the same where you would normally add the Gravatar pic. These info, are the one that get displayed on the author's page you can reach by clicking on the name of the author of the post in each post. The url of this page is something like "domain/author/user1/°,  I need to have the same data displayed for a user2, who has not published anything, at the url °domain/author/user2/°